# $unset is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$unset: {<field>: ...}}

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongodb version 3.0.1
mongoose version 4.0.3

I'm trying to do this:

```
groupsModel.updateQ({_id:group._id},{
    $unset:{"moderators":""},
    $set:{"admins":newAdmins}
})
```

And I'm getting a MongoError from the `catch` stating

`'\'$unset\' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$unset: {<field>: ...}}'`

But it isn't empty.

`moderators`, however, isn't in the schema, which is why I'm trying to remove it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce that error message, but as you've seen, Mongoose will only update fields defined in the schema. However, you can override that default behavior by including the `strict: false` option:

```
groupsModel.update(
    {_id: group._id},
    {$unset: {"moderators": ""}, $set:{"admins": newAdmins}},
    {strict: false}
)
```

Comment: Had the same error, thought I was losing it until I realized the field wasn't in my schema.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue. Did not realize that I am using 2 different name in schema and in update method.