# MongoError throws a '$addToSet' is empty error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This should be quite a simple error, but it has baffled me for quite a while.

Here is my schema:

```
const TeamSchema = new Schema({
  status: {
    type: String
  },
  total: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  wins: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    default: [],
  },
  loses: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    default: [],
});
```

My code:

```
    let objToUpdate = {
       '$addToSet': {
           'results': opponent
       },
       'total': matchDetails.total + 1,
       'status': 'Processing',
        };

    if (win) {
         objToUpdate['$addToSet'].wins = opponent;
    } else {
         objToUpdate['$addToSet'].loses = opponent;
    }

    TeamStatistics.findOneAndUpdate({_id:teamId},objToUpdate,{new:true},function(err, result){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {
       console.log(result)
   });
```

I'm facing this error:

`MongoError: '$addToSet' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$addToSet: {<field>: ...}}`

The code calculates the statistics of each team and adds the opponent of each match to either the wins array or the loses array depending on whether the team won against the opponent or lost. Regardless of result, all opponents are stored in total array as well. I need to use  '$addToSet' so the same opponent is not counted twice.

I have tried printing out the 'objToUpdate' object before calling findOneAndUpdate and I have seen that there is a value inside.

```
{
  '$addToSet': { wins: 'Team Warrios', total: 'Team Warrios' },
  status: 'Processing'
}
```

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608208/unset-is-empty-you-must-specify-a-field-like-so-unset-field) I also verified that the schema and the fields I'm trying to add to, are matching.

Referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016658/addtoset-to-an-array-but-it-gives-me-null) as well -  but it wasn't helpful.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

I'm using Mongoose - 5.1.3 and NodeJS - 12.6.0

Comment: Is `opponent` empty?

Comment: No. I checked that first. Opponent is a string that is present when I print objToUpdate just before calling findOneAndUpdate

Comment: So what are you sending to the database exactly?

Comment: Updated my question with the obj that is sent to the database. wins and total are the two arrays where I want to add 'Team Warrios'. opponent has the string 'Team Warrios' which correctly gets added to $addToSet

Answer (score 1):

$addToSet only used to add a new element to an array. You are updating both string fields and array fields within @addToSet

```
let addToSetParams = {}

 if (win) {
  addToSetParams.wins = opponent;
 } else {
  addToSetParams.loses = opponent;
 }

 let objToUpdate = {
  'total': matchDetails.total + 1,
  'status': 'Processing',
  'results': opponent,
  '$addToSet': addToSetParams
 }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question with the correct schema. total is of type number rather than array. But in your example code too, you are including matchDetails.total+1 to 'total' which is then a part of $addToSet. That should not be possible right?

Comment: Ok, I assumed total was an array. Simply move total from addToSetParams to objToUpdate. Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the clarification. But total has always been inside objToUpdate not inside addToSet. you can check my edit history. In the last edit I made it a bit more clear by moving the brackets to the next line.